"too + adjective" VS "over + adjective" (e.g.: "too ripe" VS "overripe")
oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com:
(1) Pick the tomatoes before they get too ripe.
"Too ripe" is a very odd phrase to me here.
As far as I understand, it means "overripe":
(2) Pick the tomatoes before they get overripe.
So I think (1) and (2) mean the same. Is this correct?

I've never seen "too + adjective" be instead of "over + adjective". To me, they were not supposed to be interchangeable. Was I wrong?

You're looking up the wrong word in your dictionary. The reference is to ripe, but you should look up too, and you will see several examples showing this as entirely normal English usage.

What makes you think there's something "odd" about too ripe?  See this chart showing that too ripe was actually more common that overripe until 150 years ago. "not supposed to be interchangeable"? No - you  were wrong.

...note that when the over- prefix has the sense of "excessive", it's mainly used with "adjectival past participles" (overworked, overcooked, overloaded,...), which don't work so well with too.

ripe, riper, ripest. It's gradable, and thus it can become excessive and be expressed as "too ripe".   Compare cooked.  In one sense,  either it's raw or  it's cooked, and does not admit degree. In another sense it does admit degree:  "This asparagus is overcooked".   Informal: "This asparagus is too cooked ."

Both are valid as predicative adjectives.  In fact Ngram shows too ripe to be more common up to around 1870:
too ripe v overripe as predicative adjectives
For
attributive adjectives, we normally use overripe:
overripe as an attributive adjective
Too ripe fruit does
have some hits among some false positives, but its frequency is much lower than the overripe version as shown earlier. Also, I would hyphenate it if I have to use it.

Here are a few song titles to illustrate that too ADJ is a very common construction

“Too Good to Be True”
“Too Hot to Handle”
“Too Marvelous for Words”
“Too Old to Rock 'n' Roll: Too Young to Die”
“I’m Too Sexy”
“They’re Either Too Young or Too Old”

(I’ll stop the list here. Don’t want it TL;DR.)
(I note that resorting to song lyrics without consulting other resources can be a misleading way to learn how English is used, there are also—obviously?—innumerable cases where lyrics do reflect typical usage.  These six titles are among them.)

Your examples are only appropriate for the thread if we can replace "too + adjective" with "over + adjective" in them without losing their meanings, that is: "too good" with "overgood", "too hot" with "overhot", etc. If we cannot, the answer is not appropriate for the thread.

Well, it’s hard to know what is appropriate given that your post includes the non-grammatical line “I've never seen ‘too + adjective’ was instead of ‘over + adjective’.” I suggest you edit the post to clarify exactly what it is that you are curious or unsure about. At present, its meaning is too vague (or perhaps you would prefer over vague?).

I replaced "was" with "be". Is it grammatical and clear now? Thanks.

No, it is not understandable (anyway, I don’t understand it). Instead of tweaking single words, please explain (in your post) what is unclear. What do you not see or understand? What gives you the impression that too ADJ is “very odd”?

@PaulTanenbaum: It is rather odd that overripe  was relatively uncommon compared to too ripe in the first half of C19. It's not like the over = excessive usage itself (modifying "adjectival past participle") was uncommon, as this chart shows. So arguably the question arises: Why did overripened not become established?
